# html5 trouble drawing objects in an array that are only instantiated upon key press

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am unable to find a way to draw my projectiles onto the screen after several hours of looking online and trying techniques. When I press the spacebar, a projectile is supposed to be instantiated into an empty array and then drawn to the screen but I cannot get this to work. Any help in the right direction would be most appreciated as I am confused as to how to do this. Below are the 4 files in my project for space invaders, I have shown it all so that everything can be as clear as possible. Thank you for your time.

**Game.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Game </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="ship.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <script src="projectiles.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
   <canvas id="game" width="800" height="800" tabindex="1"></canvas>
   <script>
   var game = new Game("game");
   window.onkeydown = function(e)
   {
   var key = e.keyCode;
   switch(key)
   {
   case 32://spacebar
     game.ship.trigger = 1;
     break;
   case 37: //left arrow
     game.ship.move_left();
     break;
   case 39: //right arrow
     game.ship.move_right();
     break;
   default:
     game.ship.move_static();
   }
  console.log(key);
 }
  window.onkeyup = function(e)
  {
    var key = e.keycode;
    switch(key)
    {
      case 37: //left arrow
        game.ship.move_static();
        break;
      case 39: //right arrow
        game.ship.move_static();
        break;
      default:
        game.ship.move_static();
      }
   }
   function frame (timestamp)
   {
      game.frame(timestamp);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);

   }
     window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**game.js**

```
function Game(ID)
{
   this.context = document.getElementById(ID).getContext("2d");
   this.context.rect(0, 0, 800, 800);
   this.previous;
   this.elapsed;
   this.ship = new Ship(this.context.canvas.width /2, this.context.canvas.height - 20, 100, true, 200);
   this.score = 0;
   var projectiles = [];
   //this.asteroids = this.reset_asteroids();
 }

Game.prototype.frame = function(timestamp)
{
   if(!this.previous)this.previous = timestamp;
   this.elapsed = timestamp - this.previous;
   this.update();
   this.draw();
   this.previous = timestamp;
}
Game.prototype.draw = function()
{
  this.context.clearRect(0,0,800, 800);
  this.ship.draw(this.context);
 //this.p.draw();
}
Game.prototype.update = function()
{
  this.ship.update(this.elapsed/1000, this.context.canvas.width);
  //this.Projectile.update(this.elapsed/100, ship.trigger);
}
```

**projectiles.js**

```
function Projectile(lifetime, x, y, radius, speed)
{
  this.lifetime = lifetime;
  this.life = 3.0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.y_speed = 0;
}

Projectile.prototype.draw = function(ctx)
{
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
  draw_projectile(c, this.radius, this.life)
  ctx.restore();
  Projectile.forEach(function(p)
  {
    p.draw(context);
  });
}
/*Projectile.prototype.projectile = function(elapsed)
{
  var p = new projectile(3, this.x, this.y, 20, 5);
}*/
Projectile.prototype.update = function(elapsed)
{
  this.life -= (elapsed / this.lifetime);
  Projectile.forEach(function(projectile, i, projectiles)
  {
    projectile.update(elapsed, context);
    if(projectile.this.life <= 0)
  {
    projectiles.splice(i, 1);
  }
});
 if(ship.trigger == 1)
 {
   //projectiles.push(ship.projectile(elapsed));
   projectiles.push(new Projectile(3, Ship.x, Ship.y, 20, 5));
 }
}
function draw_projectile(ctx)
{
 ctx.save();
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100%, 100%, " + (100 * lifetime);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF00FF";
 ctx.arc(0, Ship.x, Ship.y, 0, 0);
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.restore();
}
```

**ship.js**

```
function Ship(x, y, radius, guide, speed)
{
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.angle = 0;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.x_speed = 0;
}

Ship.prototype.draw = function(ctx)
{
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y); 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF00FF";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

Ship.prototype.move_left = function()
{
this.x_speed = -this.speed;
}
Ship.prototype.move_right = function()
{
  this.x_speed = this.speed;
}
Ship.prototype.move_static = function()
{
  this.x_speed = 0;
}
Ship.prototype.update = function(elapsed, width)
{
  this.x = this.x + this.x_speed * elapsed;
  if (this.x - this.radius < 0)
  {
    this.x = this.radius;
  }
  if (this.x + this.radius > width)
  {
    this.x = width - this.radius;
  }
 }
```

Comment: In your projectiles.js file, for this: `Projectile.forEach(function(p){p.draw(context);});` what is context and where is it defined?

Comment: @Jerry Ah I didn't spot this so thanks for pointing this out. I'm not entirely sure what I should replace that with though.